# Impersonation of Hadoop users

Tags: java, security, hadoop, kerberos, impersonation

I have a proxy application that receives requests and processes them by interacting with secure Hadoop cluster.

I am trying to impersonate end users (that send requests to my proxy application) so that mapper tasks, submitted by my proxy application, are run on the cluster on behalf of end users.

Is it required that username that my application is trying to impersonate exist on all mapper boxes or not? Is there a way to achieve this goal without creating  an account on cluster machines for each end user that my proxy application should impersonate?